# Mysql how to join tables more than two

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with my query,

I have tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klik_zona` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `klik` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `klik_zona` (`kode_zona`, `klik`) VALUES
(1, 45);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tampil_zona` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tanggal` date NOT NULL,
  `tampil` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`,`tanggal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tampil_zona` (`kode_zona`, `tanggal`, `tampil`) VALUES
(1, '2014-03-16', 100),
(1, '2014-03-17', 23);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zona_iklan` (
  `kode_zona` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_zona`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `zona_iklan` (`kode_zona`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
```

I have query:

```
SELECT z.kode_zona, SUM( tz.tampil ) , SUM( kz.klik )
FROM zona_iklan z
LEFT JOIN tampil_zona tz ON tz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
LEFT JOIN klik_zona kz ON kz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
GROUP BY z.kode_zona
```

but it give result:

```
kode_zona   SUM(tz.tampil)  SUM(kz.klik)    
1                123        90
2                NULL      NULL
3                NULL      NULL
```

I want get result:

```
kode_zona   SUM(tz.tampil)  SUM(kz.klik)    
1                123        45
2                NULL      NULL
3                NULL      NULL
```

please help me.. how to make query so that I get result that I hope it..

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you join two records from `tampil_zona` on to one record from `zona_iklan`, which essentially causes that one record to duplicate.  Then you are joining one record in `klik_zona` on to both of those duplicated records, causing the doubling of results that you want to avoid.

Instead, you need to aggregate the records *before* you join them, to ensure that you are always joining the records 1-to-1.

```
SELECT
  z.kode_zona, tz.tampil, kz.klik
FROM
  zona_iklan   AS z
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT kode_zona, SUM(tampil) AS tampil FROM tampil_zona GROUP BY kode_zona) AS tz
    ON tz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT kode_zona, SUM(klik)   AS klik   FROM klik_zona   GROUP BY kode_zona) AS kz
    ON kz.kode_zona = z.kode_zona
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `GROUP BY` and look at the result. You will see that there are two records with kode_zona = 1. This because there are two records in tampil_zona matching that id. You could divide by `count(*)` but that seems futile. You probably want to think about how to modify the join.